# How can we check if our app is installed for some organizations but not all of them?

Tags: python, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

We created an application for Google Apps Marketplace. Our app works only if it's installed for everyone. But the problem is, some customers install our app for some organizations, not everyone. We want to display a specific message to those customers, but the problem is that we don't know if our app is installed for some organizations, or not installed at all. Therefore, customers who installed our app for some organizations get a message which is intended for customers who didn't install our app at all. We show them the install button but nothing happens when they install our app again, because it's already installed. We want to give them instructions how to change our app's status to "on for everyone".

How can we check if our app is installed for some organizations? We get the following error message from Google:

```
Failed to retrieve access token: {
  "error" : "unauthorized_client",
  "error_description" : "Unauthorized client or scope in request."
}
```

Which is the same error message we receive for cutomers who didn't install our app at all.

This is the Python function who throws the exception:

```
  def _do_refresh_request(self, http_request):
    """Refresh the access_token using the refresh_token.

    Args:
      http_request: callable, a callable that matches the method signature of
        httplib2.Http.request, used to make the refresh request.

    Raises:
      AccessTokenRefreshError: When the refresh fails.
    """
    body = self._generate_refresh_request_body()
    headers = self._generate_refresh_request_headers()

    logger.info('Refreshing access_token')
    resp, content = http_request(
        self.token_uri, method='POST', body=body, headers=headers)
    if resp.status == 200:
      # TODO(jcgregorio) Raise an error if loads fails?
      d = simplejson.loads(content)
      self.token_response = d
      self.access_token = d['access_token']
      self.refresh_token = d.get('refresh_token', self.refresh_token)
      if 'expires_in' in d:
        self.token_expiry = datetime.timedelta(
            seconds=int(d['expires_in'])) + datetime.datetime.utcnow()
      else:
        self.token_expiry = None
      if self.store:
        self.store.locked_put(self)
    else:
      # An {'error':...} response body means the token is expired or revoked,
      # so we flag the credentials as such.
      logger.info('Failed to retrieve access token: %s' % content)
      error_msg = 'Invalid response %s.' % resp['status']
      try:
        d = simplejson.loads(content)
        if 'error' in d:
          error_msg = d['error']
          self.invalid = True
          if self.store:
            self.store.locked_put(self)
      except StandardError:
        pass
      raise AccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg)
```

**Update 1:** in Apps > Marketplace apps, an app can be on for everyone, on for selected orgs or off. We need to know the status of our app.

[image: in Apps > Marketplace apps]

**Update 2:** I tried calling `check_general_access` but also when our application is uninstalled we receive True (Application has general access). This is after we confirmed that `check_access` returned False.

```
@staticmethod
def check_access(admin_email):
    http = httplib2.Http()
    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
        SERVICE_EMAIL, 
        PRIVATE_KEY, 
        scope='https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/ https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly', 
        sub=str(admin_email),
    )
    http = credentials.authorize(http)
    try:
        service = build(serviceName='admin', version='directory_v1', http=http)
        logging.info("Application has access to admin's %s domain" % (admin_email))
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info("Application does not have access to admin's %s domain (exception: %s)" % (admin_email, e.message))
        return False

@staticmethod
def check_general_access():
    http = httplib2.Http()
    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
        SERVICE_EMAIL,
        PRIVATE_KEY,
        scope='https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/ https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly',
    )
    http = credentials.authorize(http)
    try:
        service = build(serviceName='admin', version='directory_v1', http=http)
        logging.info("Application has general access")
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info("Application does not have general access (exception: %s)" % e.message)
        return False
```

Comment: Please explain in details what "installed for an organisation" means!

Comment: @KlausD. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Update doesn't make it any clear.

Comment: @Alex.S The admin of the Google Apps domain, when he installs our app, he can select "on for everyone", "on for selected orgs" or "off". But our app only works if it's "on for everyone"

Comment: If it works only in "on for everyone" mode, why do you have other modes?

Comment: @Alex.S It's not our decision, that's how Google apps work. Maybe some apps also work when they are installed for selected orgs, our app doesn't.

Comment: I also do not understand the question.  Besides a snippet of code I'd like to see a question.  I'm surprised it hasn't been flagged.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but may have found a way. From the documentation I asserted that domain wide access is needed to impersonate a user within the target domain. Service apps do not need this for other tasks. While convoluted, you can test if you get credentials without the sub parameter to SignedJwtAssertionCredentials. If this succeeds, but adding the sub parameter fails, you're installed but not domain wide.

Let us know if this works and obviously Google has some work to do there still.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work. Please see my second update.

Answer (score -1):

You can add ping back, every hour or so call some end point. If the ping was too long ago they probably remove the app

Comment: We want to check in a specific time what is the status of our app - "on for everyone", "on for selected orgs" or "off". I don't understand what you mean by "ping back" and "call some end point", please be more specific.

Comment: You can use https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/  
There are two ways to implement what you want with GCM.
If you use the simpler HTTP connection to GCM server, your server sends an HTTP request to GCM server, which delivers the message to your device. Your device has to create its own connection to your server to send data back to the server (ping back to server).

Comment: I want to know which message I can send to Google to determine how our app is installed (or not installed). I'm looking for a specific answer. I saw the link you mentioned and I didn't find the answer there. Please notice that our app is not for android or ios, but for Google apps.